# How do I create a new object referencing an existing nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have an Item resource and an Owner resource.

```
rails g scaffold Item name:string
rails g scaffold Owner name:string

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

My problem is that I cannot create a new Item object referencing an existing Owner object.

```
In /db/migrate/create_owners.rb
def self.up
  ...
  t.integer :item_id
end

rake db:migrate   
rails c

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > o= Owner.create(:name => "Test")
 => #<Owner id: 1, name: "Test", created_at: "...", updated_at: "...">

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > i= Item.create(:owner_attributes => {"id" => Owner.last.id.to_s})
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Owner with ID=1 for Item with ID=
```

I am aware that `Item.create(:owner_id => "1")` would work in this case, but unfortunately this not a viable solution in my app. This is because I am adding and deleting nested attributes on the fly and, for example, need to create a new Item object with one existing Owner object and one new Owner object.

I found these links but couldn't work out if this is a feature or a bug in rails:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4254-assigning-nested-attributes-fails-for-new-object-when-id-is-specified
http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRails:Core/2011-05/msg00001.html

Can somebody give me an idea as to how I can make this work or have I misunderstood the correct way to use 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'??

I am using Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2p0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to create an `Item` with the owner id in the nested attributes, it tells ActiveRecord to update an existing `Owner` record. ActiveRecord cannot find the Owner record because there is no existing foreign key value (id for the item record is still nil).

```
Item.create(:owner_attributes => {"id" => Owner.last.id.to_s})
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Owner with ID=1 for Item with ID=
```

Try swapping the has_one/belongs_to associtaions and move the foreign key to the items table. Then you can set the foreign key in the parent (not nested) model and still use the nested attributes.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item
end

owner = Owner.create

Item.create(:owner_id => owner.id, :owner_attributes => {"id" => owner.id, ...})  
#=> Works!!! Note that the owner id is used twice. With some work you could probably set the id in one place or the other.
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't worked on this project for over a year, but your answer makes sense. I'll try it out (out of interest) when I have a moment.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem another way and wanted to post a simplified version of it here in case it helps anyone else. In my real app the assosciation between both resources is HABTM and the nested resource is a file attachment.

So, in the create action of the controller, I separate the parameters for the original resource and those for the nested resource.

I then further separate the nested resource into objects which exist in the database and objects which don't, putting the ids of those which do into an array.

If no existing nested objects are present, then it's plain sailing from here.

However, presuming both existing and new nested objects are present, I create a new Item object thus:
 `@item = Item.new(:attachment_ids => existing_attachment_ids)`

After that I update @item thus: 
`@item.update_attributes(original_item_params)`
`@item.update_attributes(params_for_new_nested_objects)`

Then you can call `@item.save` and have it re-render the view if any errors occur.

I still can't work out if this is a bug or a feature ir Rails. If anyone has any thoughts on the subject or my solution, I would be very glad to hear them.

Comment: Just FYI, see also this old Rails ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4254-assigning-nested-attributes-fails-for-new-object-when-id-is-specified

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is only used for `has_one` and `has_many` associations. (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html no belongs_to) It's called 'nested' so not much help there. Perhaps refactor your app?

Specifically the error case you are encountering is because it expects that the Parent should be able to find the nested model, given the id of the nested model. I.e.

```
parent.nested_model.find(id)
```

It's there it seems, basically to stop from updating child models that don't belong to the parent

Comment: Thanks. I changed the example to use has_one. Unfortunately, the problem persists. Is there any way to achieve what I am attempting, or am I best off heading back to the drawing board?

Comment: Not true, it will work for belongs_to, there just isn't an example of it there. If the has_one works, the belongs_to will work also.

Comment: @RyanBigg hmm, I must have mis-read how nested works. yeah `belongs_to` should be work if has_one works. @Jack no it looks like it's a problem as the lighthouse link (https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4254-assigning-nested-attributes-fails-for-new-object-when-id-is-specified#ticket-4254-6) you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved something similar, not perfect though. have a look! My test fails a lot though now as I don't know Factory Girl better.

[creating an object with has_many association results in item can not be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163166/creating-an-object-with-has-many-association-results-in-item-can-not-be-blank/18182704#18182704)