# creating an object with has_many association results in item can not be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following associations and the related controller, in my form I am adding every field as it should be. But I still get an error **Ratings item can't be blank** when I try to create an Item. I am using **Rails 4.0** . I did searched extensively for this but could not still find what I am doing wrong. Thankyou!

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :name , :length => { minimum: 3 }
  validates :category , :length => { minimum: 3 }
end

class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :item_id, :presence => true
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :less_than_or_equal_to => 5

end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show]
  before_action :user_signed_in?, only: :create

  def create
    @item = Item.new
    @rating = @item.ratings.build
    @rating.comment = params[:item][:ratings_attributes][:comment]
    @rating.rating = params[:item][:ratings_attributes][:rating]
    @rating.user_id = current_user.id

    @item.name = params[:item][:name]
    @item.url = params[:item][:url]
    @item.full_address = params[:item][:full_address]
    @item.city = params[:item][:city]
    @item.country = params[:item][:country]
    @item.category = params[:item][:category]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        #TODO create rating here (First rating of an Item)
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to inmyopnion"
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :url, :full_address, :city, :country, :category, :ratings_attributes => [:rating, :comment])
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    #TODO: should display should sign in to rate an item
    redirect_to(root_url) unless signed_in?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your controller! Since you are allowing nested_attributes this should be sufficient:

```
@item = Item.create(params[:item])
```

The problem might be caused by @rating object not being saved.

Comment: @item = Item.create(params[:item]) gives an forbidden attributes error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by commenting the below given line in

```
class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :item_id, :presence => true
```

but my association `rspec test` fails and saves a `Ratings` without an `item_id`. 
Rest of the code is similar to what I posted as

```
@item = Item.create(params[:item])
```

gives `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

Comment: Alright Finally found an answer, not able to refractor as may be I am doing a small typo somewhere (not sure though)

Answer (score 0):

Alright much playing with the code and docs of `nested_attributes` finally a working program that validates association too. These are the changes (marked in between ** .... **) listed below

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy, **inverse_of: :item**
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :name , :length => { minimum: 3 }
  validates :category , :length => { minimum: 3 }
end

class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, **inverse_of: :ratings**
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :item
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :less_than_or_equal_to => 5
end
```

Still not able to create one from `@item = Item.create(params[:item])` which still gives an gives 
`ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`  as suggested by @BroiSatse and also the docs of `nested_attributes` that should not be the case

the problem might be in

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :url, :full_address, :city, :country, :category, :ratings_attributes => [:rating, :comment])
  end
```

will work on to resolve that too and post an answer if I find a solution.